# moment - Get end of day by timezone

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I may be confusing myself, however we have multiple timezones for a specific application, we want to know `midnight tonight` for the current users timezone.

`moment().endOf('day').tz('Australia/Sydney')` -> `Sat Nov 14 2020 10:59:59 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)`

Either I'm not understanding it correctly but shouldn't the above work?

Comment: you are asking for endof day first, then converting to australia/syndney, do it the other way round

Comment: Presumably you are in UTC+0?